# Sum table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table and I want to allow submitting the form if and only if the total of each row must be =100 not less nor more
and the total of each column must be <=100 and not more than 100

This is the old scenario each row and each column must be = 100.
[image]

Demo CODE:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
disableSave();

$(".sum").on("input", function() {
  sumThisClass("1");
  sumThisClass("2");
  sumThisClass("3");
  sumThisClass("4");
  sumThisClass("5");
  sumThisClass("6");
  sumThisClass("7");
  validateForm();
});

function validateForm() {
  var hasError = $(".error").length > 0;
  if (hasError) {
    disableSave();
    return;
  }
  
  var expectedTotal = $(".total").length * 100;
  console.log(expectedTotal, getCurrentTotal());
  if (expectedTotal == getCurrentTotal()) {
    enableSave();
  }
  else {
    disableSave();
  }
}

function getCurrentTotal() {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    $(".total").each(function (index, el) {
    var elValue = parseInt($(el).text());
    if (!isNaN(elValue)) {
      sumTotal += parseInt($(el).text());
    }
  });
  return sumTotal;
}

function disableSave() {
  $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", true);
}

function enableSave() {
  $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", false);
}

function sumThisClass(className) {

  var sumTotal = 0;
  $("." + className).each(function(index, el) {
    var elValue = parseInt($(el).val());
    if (!isNaN(elValue)) {
      sumTotal += parseInt($(el).val());
    }
  });
  
  $(".sum-" + className).text(sumTotal);

  if (sumTotal > 100) {
    $(".sum-" + className).append("<div class='error'>cannot be greater than 100</div>");
  }

}
});
</script>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 1 5" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 1 6" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 1 7" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td class="total sum-1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 2 5" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 2 6" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="sum 2 7" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td class="total sum-2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td class="total sum-5"></td>
    <td class="total sum-6"></td>
    <td class="total sum-7"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" id="btn-save"/>
```

[**Demo Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c4jhyL0/)

I tried to change it but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: is your column always 2x3 ?

Comment: if use of jquery is not mandatory, I would strongly recommend you to use angularJs for this kind of operation. This task becomes much much easier using angular.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz yes. this scenario is simple I'm drawing the table from db in php and the code is much complicated. I would really appreciate if you do small changes in the demo to transfer that to my complicated system.

Comment: @maddy23285 thats depends on the knowledge and subjective preference

Comment: No no its more than that for example 9x7

Comment: in case 2x3. total column must be 100, total row must be 100 and total of them must be 500, not less not more?

Comment: No. sum of each row "total the 5rth column" must be = 100 not less nor more AND sum of each column "Total the 5rth column" must be <=100 and not more than 100

Comment: I have a problem in explaining seriously :") [[the only change between the result of my code and the result I want is to accept <100 total of each column that it. So instead of all rows must be = 100 and all columns must be = 100, total of columns can be less]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var isvalid=true;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#test").prop("disabled",true);
    $(".tabbody input[type=number]").blur(function(){
        validateSubmit();
    });
});
function validateSubmit()
{
    var retval = sumRowVals();
    $("#test").prop("disabled",!retval);
    $("#msgdiv").html(retval ? "":"Invalid inputs!!!");
}
function sumRowVals()
{
    isvalid=true;
    resetFigs();
    var rindx=1;
    $(".tabbody tr").each(function(){
        var temp=0;
        var cindx=1;
        $("input[type=number]",this).each(function(){
            var elval = !isNaN($(this).val()) ? parseInt($(this).val()):0;
            var sumcol = $("#ccol"+cindx);
            $(sumcol).html(parseInt($(sumcol).html())+elval);
            temp=temp+elval;
            cindx++;
            if(elval > 100){isvalid=false;}
            if(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 100){isvalid=false;}
        });
        if(rindx != $('.tabbody tr').length)
        {
            if(temp != 100){isvalid=false;}
            $("#rcol"+rindx).html(temp);
        }
        rindx++;
    });
    return isvalid;
}
function resetFigs()
{
    $('*[id*=ccol]').each(function() {
    $(this).html("0");
});
}
function SubmitForm()
{
    // your form submit code
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery2.0.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table border=1 cellpadding="5">
<tbody class='tabbody'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td id="rcol1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td id="rcol2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="ccol1"></td>
      <td id="ccol2"></td>
      <td id="ccol3"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
</td>
    </tr> 

</tbody>
</table>
<div id="msgdiv" style="color:red;line-height:30px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a rough idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var isvalid=true;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#test").prop("disabled",true);
    $(".tabbody input[type=number]").blur(function(){
        validateSubmit();
    });
});
function validateSubmit()
{
    var retval = sumRowVals();
    $("#test").prop("disabled",!retval);
    $("#msgdiv").html(retval ? "":"Invalid inputs!!!");
}
function sumRowVals()
{
    isvalid=true;
    resetFigs();
    var rindx=1;
    $(".tabbody tr").each(function(){
        var temp=0;
        var cindx=1;
        $("input[type=number]",this).each(function(){
            var elval = !isNaN($(this).val()) ? parseInt($(this).val()):0;
            var sumcol = $("#ccol"+cindx);
            $(sumcol).html(parseInt($(sumcol).html())+elval);
            temp=temp+elval;
            cindx++;
            if(elval > 100){isvalid=false;}
            if(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 100){isvalid=false;}
        });
        if(rindx != $('.tabbody tr').length)
        {
            if(temp != 100){isvalid=false;}
            $("#rcol"+rindx).html(temp);
        }
        rindx++;
    });
    return isvalid;
}
function resetFigs()
{
    $('*[id*=ccol]').each(function() {
    $(this).html("0");
});
}
function SubmitForm()
{
    // your form submit code
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border=1 cellpadding="5">
<tbody class='tabbody'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td id="rcol1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
        <td id="rcol2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="ccol1"></td>
      <td id="ccol2"></td>
      <td id="ccol3"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
</td>
    </tr> 

</tbody>
</table>
<div id="msgdiv" style="color:red;line-height:30px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will work with unknown number of columns and rows

Comment: Sorry for that :") 1. Thanks for making it work with unknown number of rows and columns 2. I need to show the total as per user interning data, you didn't achieve this. 3. your code didn't work with my inputs please check the image of my question try to inter same number and check the result + read my last comment up there.

Comment: I tried the same input as in image. It says valid input. I have a doubt--- Column = [Sum of column Value] or Cell value? My code will return true if Sum of all values in a row is = 100, sum of all values in a column <=100 , when cell value is <= 100, Cell or sum of column values can have 0 but sum of row values must be equal to 100

Comment: I have edited my code. Now calculations and validation will be done as soon as user leaves the input field. If you want this to be done while entering the input then use .keyup instead of .blur   .Sorry, I don't know if I get your logic. Please make some changes accordingly if needed. ;-P ;-)

Comment: Run this to check how it is working. I have checked your jsfiddle code you need to add jquery. For that you need click at left top of script window where it says Javascript(no library(pure js)) and select jquery in frameworks & extension section.

Comment: Hi @maddy23285 I'm in trouble changing your code to a new validation rule. Now I want the total of each row to be >0 and <=100 while total of each column must be =100 not less nor more. please help me I couldn't achieve it

Comment: Just change this line of code **if(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 100){isvalid=false;}** with this **if(!(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 0 && parseInt($(sumcol).html()) <= 100)){isvalid=false;}**

Comment: What about this line ***if(temp != 100){isvalid=false;}*** ?. after the change I test it with the correct scenario but it gives the error of invalid inputs.

Comment: the correct scenario I used is total of each row 100 and total of each column 100 but the error still shows

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's gonna work for you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    disableSave();

    $(".sum").on("input", function() {
      sumThisClass("1");
      sumThisClass("2");
      sumThisClass("3");
      sumThisClass("4");
      sumThisClass("5");
      sumThisClass("6");
      sumThisClass("7");
      validateForm();
    });

    function validateForm() {
      var hasError = $(".error").length > 0;
      if (hasError) {
        disableSave();
        return;
      }

      if( tmp['sum_1'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_2'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_5'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_6'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_7'] <= 100) {
          enableSave();
      } else {
        disableSave();
      }
    }

    function getCurrentTotal() {
      var sumTotal = 0;
      $(".total").each(function (index, el) {
        var elValue = parseInt($(el).text());
        if (!isNaN(elValue)) {
          sumTotal += parseInt($(el).text());
        }
      });
      return sumTotal;
    }
    function disableSave() {
      $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    function enableSave() {
      $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    var tmp = {
      sum_1:null,
      sum_2:null,
      sum_5:null,
      sum_6:null,
      sum_7:null
    };
    function sumThisClass(className) {

      var sumTotal = 0;

      $("." + className).each(function(index, el) {
        var elValue = parseInt($(el).val());
        if (!isNaN(elValue)) {
          sumTotal += parseInt($(el).val());
        }
      });

      $(".sum-" + className).text(sumTotal);

      if (sumTotal > 100) {
        $(".sum-" + className).append("<div class='error'>cannot be greater than 100</div>");
      }

      tmp['sum_'+className] = sumTotal;

    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 1 5" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 1 6" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 1 7" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td class="total sum-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 2 5" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 2 6" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sum 2 7" min="0" max="100">
      </td>
      <td class="total sum-2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
      <td class="total sum-5"></td>
      <td class="total sum-6"></td>
      <td class="total sum-7"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" id="btn-save"/>
```

Comment: You didn't achieve my condition (each row must be =100 & each column must be <=100 and not >100) if all correct SAVE button enabled. otherwise, error messages will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

you will change the old condition by this:

```
if( tmp['sum_1'] == 100 && 
          tmp['sum_2'] == 100 && 
          tmp['sum_5'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_6'] <= 100 && 
          tmp['sum_7'] <= 100) {
          enableSave();
} else {
        disableSave();
}
```

Comment: its not doable but I'll try to generalize it

Answer (score 0):

my code looks dirty, but i just want you to know what exactly i did in each line.

btw, you can try this

```js
$(function(){
 $('.btn-create').click(function(){
  var col = parseInt($('.count-column').val());
  var row = parseInt($('.count-row').val());
  
  $('table').html('');
  
  var head='<thead><tr><th></th>';
  var foot='<tfoot><tr><th>TOTAL ROW</th>';
  var tr = '';
  for(a=0; a< row;a++){
   tr += '<tr><td>row '+a+'</td>';
   for(b=0; b< col;b++){
    tr +='<td><input type="number" class="sum error-row" data-row="'+a+'" data-col="'+b+'" min="0" value="0" max="100"></td>';//all must have error row to prevent 0 0 0 0
    if(a==0) {foot +='<th class="total sumcol-'+b+'">0</th>';
    head +='<th>col '+b+'</th>';}
   }
   tr +='<td class="total sumrow-'+a+'">0</td>';
   tr +='</tr>';
   
   
  }
  head +='<th>TOTAL COL</th></tr></thead>';
  foot +='<th class=""><input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" disabled id="btn-save"/></th></tr></tfoot>';
  $('table').append(head+tr+foot);
  $('#btn-save').prop('disabled', true);
 });
 
 $("body").on('click', 'input[type="number"]',function () {
    $(this).select();
 });
 
 $('.btn-show').click(function(){
  console.log($('table').html());
 })
 
 $("table").on("change", '.sum', function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  if(isNaN(val)) val= 0;
  $(this).val(val); //parse int here, so you dont need parse all of them again
  var col = $(this).data('col');
  var row = $(this).data('row');
  
  //count row
  var rows = $('.sum[data-row="'+row+'"]');
  var total = 0;
  $.each(rows, function(i,e){
   total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('.sumrow-'+row).text(total);
  if(total == 100)  rows.removeClass('error-row');
  else{
   rows.addClass('error-row'); 
  }
  
  //count col
  var cols = $('.sum[data-col="'+col+'"]');
  var total = 0;
  $.each(cols, function(i,e){
   total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('.sumcol-'+col).text(total);
  if(total <= 100)  cols.removeClass('error-col');
  else{
   cols.addClass('error-col'); 
  }
  
  validate();
 });
 
 function validate(){
  if($('.error-col, .error-row').length > 0) $('#btn-save').prop('disabled', true);
  else $('#btn-save').prop('disabled', false);
 }
 
});
```

```css
.error-row, .error-col{border: 1px solid red;}
table tfoot tr th:not(:first-child){font-weight: 400;}
```

```html
how many rows x column <input type="number" min="1" value="2" class="count-row"> X <input min="1" value="3" type="number" class="count-column"> <button class="btn-create">create</button> <button class="btn-show">show DOM</button>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<table></table>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this demo [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) was used because it makes dealing with form controls easier with it's terse compact syntax. Added `<output>` tags to each total cells. All `<input>`s and `<output>`s have an id that's associated with it's cell (`<td>`).

**Details are commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
/* Using old school HTMLFormControlsCollection */

// Reference the first (and only) form */
var f0 = document.forms[0];

// Collection of ALL form controls of f0
var F = f0.elements;

/* Handle any input events on f0 by calling 
|| callback function tableCalc()
*/
f0.oninput = tableCalc;

function tableCalc(e) {

  /* if the element receiving any user input (e.target)
  || is NOT the element that listens for input event
  || (e.currentTarget or f0) then...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    /* Get e.target's id and determine the associated
    || outputs by e.target's id.
    */ // Example for <input id='r1c2'>
    // 'r1c2'
    var RC = e.target.id;
    // '1'
    var row = RC.charAt(1);
    // '2'
    var col = RC.charAt(3);
    // 'R1'
    var R = 'R' + row;
    // 'C2'
    var C = 'C' + col;

    /* Calculate the sums for each row */
    F[R].value = F['r' + row + 'c0'].valueAsNumber + F['r' + row + 'c1'].valueAsNumber + F['r' + row + 'c2'].valueAsNumber;

    /* Calculate the sums for each col */
    F[C].value = F['r0c' + col].valueAsNumber + F['r1c' + col].valueAsNumber;
  }

  /* if both rows === 100 AND none of the col exceed 100
  || enable the button
  */
  if (Number(F.R0.value) === 100 && Number(F.R1.value) === 100 && Number(F.C0.value) < 101 && Number(F.C1.value < 101) && Number(F.C2.value) < 101) {
    F.b0.disabled = false;

    // Otherwise the button is disabled
  } else {
    F.b0.disabled = true;
  }

  /* Collect all output tags into a NodeList then 
  || convert it into an array
  */
  var totals = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('output'));

  // Run totals array through map() on each output...
  totals.map(function(out, idx, totals) {

    /* Get the associated error cell by matching
    || output.id to td.className
    */
    var msg = document.querySelector('.' + out.id);

    // Get output's value
    var val = Number(out.value);

    // if it exceeds 100...
    if (val > 100) {

      // Display message in associated error cell
      msg.textContent = `Exceeds 100`;
      out.style.color = 'red';
      out.style.textAlign = 'center';

      // Otherwise clear the error
    } else {
      msg.textContent = '';
      out.style.color = 'black';
      out.style.textAlign = 'right';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: right
}

output {
  width: 7ch
}

button {
  font: inherit
}

td {
  max-width: 8ch;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<form id='F0'>
  <table id='T0'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>C0</th>
        <th>C1</th>
        <th>C2</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id='r0c0' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id='r0c1' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id='r0c2' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--Row 1 total-->
          <output id='R0' for='r0c0 r0c1 r0c2'>0</output>
        </td>
        <!--Row 1 error cell-->
        <td class='R0 error' style='max-width:12ch'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id='r1c0' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id='r1c1' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id='r1c2' type='number' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--Row 2 total-->
          <output id='R1' for='r1c0 r1c1 r1c2'>0</output>
        </td>
        <!--Row 2 error cell-->
        <td class='R1 error' style='max-width:12ch'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--Column totals-->
          <output id='C0' for='r0c0 r1c0'>0</output>
        </td>
        <td>
          <output id='C1' for='r0c1 r1c1'>0</output>
        </td>
        <td>
          <output id='C2' for='r0c2 r1c2'>0</output>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--Placed button here so it doesn't shift-->
          <button id='b0' disabled>SAVE</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <!--Error cells for column totals-->
        <td class='C0 error'></td>
        <td class='C1 error'></td>
        <td class='C2 error'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```