# sum of column using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to sum of column With `OnKeyup` or `OnChange`

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expenses").on('keyup change', calculateSum);
});
function calculateSum() {
  var $input = $(this);
  var $row = $input.closest('tr');
  var sum = 0;
  $row.find(".expenses").each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
  });
  $row.find(".expenses_sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>sl</th>
    <th>TA</th>
    <th>DA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Total</td>
   <td><input class="expenses_sum"></td>
   <td><input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what errors are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991320/sum-table-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when the "context" of the input that matters: you want to update the sum that is in the **same column** where the input element was updated.

What you can do is:

1. Get the index of the `<td>` element the input belongs to
2. Calculate the sum of all expenses belonging to the same column. This is done by filtering (using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)) all `.expenses` elements to ensure that their parent's `<td>` index matches that you've determined in step 2
3. Set the sum on the corresponding `.expenses_sum` element in the same column. This is again, done by filtering all `.expenses_sum` elements and only getting the one whose parent `<td>` index matches

Some additional pro-tips:

- Listen to the `onInput` event. For input elements, that covers `onKeyUp` and `onChange` events, for convenience.
- Use `<input type="number" />` to prevent users from erroneously entering non-numerical characters
- Use `<input readonly />` on the `.expenses_sum` element, so that users don't fiddle with that sum by their own
- Remember to cast the value of the input elements to a number. This can be done by using the `+` operator, i.e. `+this.value`. Remember that as per spec, all input elements, regardless their `type`, always has their value in type of `string`
- Chain `.each(calculateSum)` to your original selection, so that you also compute the sum when the page is first loaded, i.e. `$(".expenses").on('input', calculateSum).each(calculateSum);`. This is very helpful when the `.expenses` elements might be pre-populated with values from the server-side (or if you have manually defined `value="..."`), for example.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expenses").on('input', calculateSum).each(calculateSum);
});

function calculateSum() {
  // Get the index of the parent `<td>` element
  var cellIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
  
  // Get the values of expenses in the same column as the `<td>` element
  var allExpensesInSameColumn = $('.expenses').map(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('td').index() !== cellIndex)
      return;
      
    return +this.value;
  }).get();
  
  // Calculate the sum from returned array of values
  var sumOfExpensesInSameColumn = allExpensesInSameColumn.reduce(function(acc, curVal) {
    return acc + curVal;
  });
  
  // Set the sum on the `.expenses_sum` element in the corresponding column
  $('.expenses_sum').each(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('td').index() !== cellIndex)
      return;

    this.value = sumOfExpensesInSameColumn;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>sl</th>
    <th>TA</th>
    <th>DA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="expenses" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="expenses" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input class="expenses" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="expenses" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td><input class="expenses_sum" readonly></td>
    <td><input class="expenses_sum" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```